# Logic - equivalence between sentences

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

By having the following sentences:
$$\alpha=\forall x,y[S(x,y)\rightarrow [S(x,x)\lor y\neq d]]$$
$$\beta=\exists x,y[\lnot S(x,d)\land S(x,y)\land y=d]$$
$$\gamma=\forall x,y[x=d \rightarrow[S(y,y)\lor\lnot S(y,x)]]$$

Which equivalence to which?

---

I found out that $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are equivalence since I can use identities and get the exact same thing. We shall use the next identity: $\alpha\rightarrow \beta \equiv \lnot \alpha \lor \beta$. Therefore we have that: $$\alpha = \forall x,y[\lnot S(x,y)\lor S(x,x)\lor y\neq d]$$
and $$\gamma = \forall x,y[x\neq d \lor S(y,y)\lor \lnot S(y,x)]$$
Now, we will exchange $x$ by $y$ and the opposite, which yields:
$$\gamma =\forall y,x[\lnot S(x,y) \lor S(x,x)\lor y\neq d] $$
Thus, we have got that $\alpha \equiv \gamma$

However, I can see that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not equivalenced because $\beta \equiv \lnot \alpha$, but I am not sure if it is correct. Thank you.

Comment: $\beta$ is not equivalent to  $\lnot \alpha$, that would be $\exists x,y[S(x,y) \land \lnot S(x,x) \land (y=d)]$

Comment: @HennoBrandsma do you agree with what I said before? which then equivalent to which? can you elaborate please?

Comment: Could you add a reasoning why $\alpha \equiv \gamma$?

Comment: Yes of course I can.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma see the edit

Comment: Hint: to show $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not equivalent, try coming up with an example of $S$ which makes one true and the other false. (Extra hint: try really simple examples first, like $S(x, y)$ never true or always true.)

Comment: @RobArthan Oh I see! Did I show the equivalence of $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ right?

Comment: Yes. Your argument for the equivalence of $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ is fine.

Comment: @RobArthan thank you so much!